# Java, Number of n-words in a text

Tags: java, string, cpu-word

The purpose of this class is to count the number of occurrences of every n-character words in a text entered by the user. I think there are some mistakes in the method occurrenceNumber because I obtain 228 for every n-character word. Where is the error ?

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TempTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Enter the integer n");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        char[] array = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', ' ' };
        StringBuffer[] table = createTotalTable(n, array);

        System.out.println("Enter the text ");
        StringBuffer text = new StringBuffer("");
        try {
            text = new StringBuffer(in.readLine());
        } catch (IOException a) {
            System.out.println("Input-Output problem");
        }
        StringBuffer text_formatted = format(text.toString());
        System.out.println("The formatted text is \n" + text_formatted.toString() + "\n");

        System.out.println("Now we print all the n-character words in alphabetic order. Press enter to proceed. ");
        try {
            in.readLine();
        } catch (IOException b) {
            System.out.println("Input-Output problem");
        }
        for (StringBuffer word : table)
            System.out.println(word.toString());

        int[] occurrenceTable = createList(text_formatted, table, n);

        System.out.println("Now we print all the n-words contained in the text with the number of occurrences. Press enter to proceed.");
        try {
            in.readLine();
        } catch (IOException c) {
            System.out.println("Input-Output problem");
        }

        for (int u = 0; u < pow(27, n); u++)
            System.out.println(table[u].toString() + ", " + occurrenceTable[u]);

    }

    public static StringBuffer[] createTotalTable(int n, char[] a) { // this method create an array containing all the n-words in alphabetic order

        StringBuffer[] table = new StringBuffer[pow(27, n)];
        for (int w = 0; w < pow(27, n); w++)
            table[w] = new StringBuffer("");

        for (int h = 1; h <= n; h++) {
            for (int u = 0; u < pow(27, h - 1); u++) {

                for (int j = 0; j < 27; j++) {

                    for (int x = pow(27, n - h + 1) * u + pow(27, n - h) * j; x < pow(27, n - h + 1) * u + pow(27, n - h) * (j + 1); x++)
                        table[x] = table[x].append(a[j]);
                }

            }

        }

        return table;
    }

    public static int pow(int a, int b) { // the method Math.pow modified

        int tot = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < b; i++)
            tot = a * tot;

        return tot;
    }

    public static int occurrenceNumber(StringBuffer testo, StringBuffer parola, int n) { // this method is aimed to calculate the number of occurrences of a
                                                                                            // word of length n in a text
        int tot = 0;

        if (n > testo.length())
            System.out.println("The integer is bigger than the text's length ");
        else {
            for (int i = 0; i <= testo.length() - n; i++) {
                if (testo.substring(i, i + n) == parola.toString())
                    tot += 1;

            }

        }

        return tot;
    }

    public static int[] createList(StringBuffer str, StringBuffer[] tabella, int n) { // this method is aimed to create an array containing for every position
                                                                                        // the number of occurrences of the corresponding word in the text

        int[] occurrenceTable = new int[pow(27, n)];

        for (int i = 0; i < pow(27, n); i++)
            occurrenceTable[i] = occurrenceNumber(str, tabella[i], n);

        return occurrenceTable;

    }

    public static StringBuffer format(String s) { // this method is aimed to
        // eliminate from the text all non-alphabetic characters and multiple spaces

        s = s.toLowerCase();
        StringBuffer b = new StringBuffer();
        int m = s.length();
        int conta_spazi = 0;
        StringBuffer h = new StringBuffer(s);
        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            switch (h.charAt(i)) {
            case 'a':
                break;

            case 'A':
                break;

            case 'b':
                break;

            case 'B':
                break;

            case 'c':
                break;

            case 'C':
                break;

            case 'd':
                break;

            case 'D':
                break;

            case 'e':
                break;

            case 'E':
                break;

            case 'f':
                break;

            case 'F':
                break;

            case 'g':
                break;

            case 'G':
                break;

            case 'h':
                break;

            case 'H':
                break;

            case 'i':
                break;

            case 'I':
                break;

            case 'j':
                break;

            case 'J':
                break;

            case 'k':
                break;

            case 'K':
                break;

            case 'l':
                break;

            case 'L':
                break;

            case 'm':
                break;

            case 'M':
                break;

            case 'n':
                break;

            case 'N':
                break;

            case 'o':
                break;

            case 'O':
                break;

            case 'p':
                break;

            case 'P':
                break;

            case 'q':
                break;

            case 'Q':
                break;

            case 'r':
                break;

            case 'R':
                break;

            case 's':
                break;

            case 'S':
                break;

            case 't':
                break;

            case 'T':
                break;

            case 'u':
                break;

            case 'U':
                break;

            case 'v':
                break;

            case 'V':
                break;

            case 'w':
                break;

            case 'W':
                break;

            case 'x':
                break;

            case 'X':
                break;

            case 'y':
                break;

            case 'Y':
                break;

            case 'z':
                break;

            case 'Z':
                break;

            default:
                h.setCharAt(i, ' ');

            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {

            if (h.charAt(i) == ' ')
                conta_spazi++;
            else
                conta_spazi = 0;

            if (conta_spazi <= 1)
                b = b.append(h.charAt(i));

        }

        return b;

    }
}
```

Comment: Be aware that there is too much processing going on here. For example, entering an n of 6 or above will immediately crash the system on my IDE, due to lack of memory.

Comment: I'd advise you to go away and debug your program, then come back and edit this question with a much shorter piece of code that can be debugged. It could take a long time to debug this - you need to help the people on the forum by only providing the code that's necessary!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To compare 2 strings you need to call the `equals` method and not `==`

You should replace:

```
 if(testo.substring(i,i+n) == parola.toString())
```

**With**

```
if(testo.substring(i,i+n).equals(parola.toString()))
```

Comment: I followed your suggestion, but now I obtain for every n-word the result 228

Comment: I answered your question _I think there are some mistakes in the method occurrenceNumber because I obtain 0 for every n-character word. Where is the error ?_ now if you aren't getting the good result then you should consider review the algorithm and debug your code or ask an new question.

Comment: Don't ask a new question. Amend this one - there's not enough difference in what you are asking.

Comment: ok, but mabbas answered the previous question so I accepted your answer

Comment: @boris: Be aware that this is now the 4th question you've asked relating to this. Let's try and make it work this time, rather than adding bits and pieces on and asking new questions!!

Comment: I tried to edit the question but I can't because one person edited before

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't figure out the logic you are implementing. However you can find the count in a simpler approach :

```
    // extract n-char words and add them to a list
    ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(^|\\s)\\w{" + n + "}(\\s|$)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text_formatted);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        int k = 0;
        arr.add(matcher.group(k++).trim());
    }
    // sort the list 
    Collections.sort(arr);
    // find the count and print
    String prev = "";
    int count = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
        if (prev.equals(arr.get(i))) {
            count++;
        } else {
            count = 1;
            System.out.print(arr.get(i)+" : ");
        }
        if(i<arr.size()-1 && !arr.get(i).equals(arr.get(i+1)))
        {
            System.out.println(count);
        }
        prev = arr.get(i);
    }
    System.out.println(count);
```

Hoping this will help.